# Regex for multiple phrases in one phrase

Tags: javascript, regex

I really have no other way of explaining this however, I need a regular expression to match in javascript.

I have a spam prevention to match a string however, I would like multiple guesses and match those using regex.

As an example, I want to match **thiswordhere**. To return true, the matches can be:

- thiswordhere
- thisword
- wordhere
- word

It must be a standalone word so no spaces and no responses like **word word** or **thisword word**

Four possible outcomes. I'm very new to regex and all I could get using regexr is:

`/(thisword)[here]/g`

Which couldn't do the trick. I'm going to be studying regex a lot these coming months so I would like to see the solution for this example.

Comment: Just wondering, what kind of "spam prevention" are you doing with Javascript? You realize it can be easily disabled or overcome (in the browser) or ignored/side-stepped, right?

Comment: I will also do it server side.

Comment: The client validation is with bootstrapValidator which requires regex for exact matching of a field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match **only** that text on a line (or in your string), you can simply add the start `^` and end `$` delimiters to your regex:

```
/^((?:this)?word(?:here)?)$/g
```

[Example](http://regex101.com/r/fZ0zN2/1)

---

A quick and easy way is to specify those particular outcomes as options:

```
/(thiswordhere|thisword|wordhere|word)/g
```

[Example](http://regex101.com/r/pA3sD8/1)

A slightly better option might be to specify that the "word" part is always needed, with "this" optional on the left, and "here" optional on the right:

```
/((?:this)?word(?:here)?)/g
```

[Example](http://regex101.com/r/hJ9oU9/1)

---

FYI - your regex is saying match "thisword" literally, followed by any of the four characters "h", "e", "r", "e". What you need to say is "match word, optionally preceded by "this" and optionally followed by "here" (example above).

Comment: "thiswordhere".match(/(this)?(word)(here)?/g)[0]

Comment: Must be standalone to prevent **thisword word word thiswordhere** as a response. So no spacing before or after would do it.

Comment: You mean you only want to match these if they are all the input is? [Like this for example?](http://regex101.com/r/fZ0zN2/1)

Comment: Yes, the input can't contain anymore than thiswordhere wordhere or word, nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex like this:

```
\b(?:this)?word(?:here)?\b
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/hL1pG6/2)**

[image]